# Access SNI websites from Azure web role

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-roles, windows-server-2012, sni

We have an Azure web role that's used to send HttpWebRequests so it's imperative that it is able to access any type of website. Recently, we noticed that SNI websites cannot be accessed; TLS handshake errors are being reported in the event log:

> A fatal alert was received from the remote endpoint. The TLS protocol defined fatal alert code is 40.

The web role machine is running Windows Server 2012 with all the latest updates applied and the SNI websites cannot be accessed from its IE10 either (although Chrome can see them). We have another Windows Server 2012 machine set up as a virtual machine, and unlike the web role, that machine has no trouble accessing the SNI sites.

We noticed that Azure web roles now come with very few root certificates preinstalled. We tried manually installing the root certificate but that didn't help.